# Should the canonical Q&A on NullReferenceExceptions tag common .NET languages?

Tags: discussion, tags, specific-question

I like [the canonical Q&A on a `NullReferenceException`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it). I like it a lot. I like it so much that I want to use it to close questions on the topic of NRE's.

Except, since it is not tagged as [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) (at least, that's why I assume this is), it does not get picked up by the search inside the close-as-duplicate window (searching for *nullreference* and *nullreferenceexception*).

When looking at the revision history I notice that the tag has been added and removed several times already.

*Why do some members of the community not want that tag in there?*

I assume this is done to keep it general and just stick to the [.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net) tag? Nevertheless I believe tagging the most relevant .NET languages would be a good way to go.

Comment: So, [here's a question tagged with C#, but not .net.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13060080/impossible-nullreferenceexception). When I try to close as a dupe, I see [the canonical question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it), currently tagged as .net but not C#, at the top of the list. I question your assumption.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta: that question has the *nullreferenceexception* tag which probably puts it at the top. Most questions do not. For example [this](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/23668307/revisions) is one that I closed yesterday evening and it didn't show up (although the next time I'll try adding that tag first).

Answer (score 4):

It shouldn't be tagged with [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) because it is not a C# specific feature, it is a 'feature' or component of the .Net framework.

Comment: Right but if people are using the c# tag or the vb.net tag that isn't actually helpful or good communication as they won't find it.

Comment: @meh-uk If it was decided to add language tags to it, then where do you stop? There are lots of .Net languages, and there is a limit on the number of tags you can have. Do we have `c#` and `vb.net` only? Or do we also have `f#`? Who makes that call? The languages are developed independently - what if a new language feature changes how NREs are generated or handled, do you then remove the tag for that language? I know it isn't easy to find, but adding a language tag isn't necessarily the right way to fix that.

Comment: You could at least manage to include all the major languages, as that helps the most people, and if you add more it's not the end of the world.